# Excel 2007 error "400 visual basic", when deleting worksheet

Tags: vba, excel-2007, worksheet

I've read [this](http://www.teachexcel.com/excel-help/excel-how-to.php?i=563256), [this](https://www.add-ins.com/support/microsoft-visual-basis-error-400.htm), and [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/error-400-in-ms-excel-2007), and none of the "solutions" worked for me.

I've restored MS Office Enterprise 2007 to default settings by running the Repair tool, via Control-Panel -> Add/Remove Programs -> MS Office Enterprise 2007 -> Change.

Every time I open a new workbook and it has the default 3 worksheets, when I try and delete a worksheet (right-click -> DELETE), I get that dreaded "400" error within a "Visual Basic" dialog box.

I found by trial-and-error, the only way to delete a worksheet was to use the Delete Worksheet command from the Toolbar custom menus.

There is obviously a macro attached to the right-click delete option, but I don't know how to remove it!

Comment: Do you have any Excel files from folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel`? If you try rename this folder while Excel is running and if it fails, most likely a binary file/addin file is executed automatically when Excel launches. Does it occur in Excel Safe mode (`excel.exe /safe`)?

Comment: @PatricK no it does not occur in Safe mode! Wow. Thanks I am finally pin pointing this. Most likely an exe like you said. I am looking at the AppData folder now

Comment: @PatricK unfortunately that's as far as I got. I noticed I have a Developer tab (which I need to access Visual Basic, VBA, etc) and it has XML Expansion Packs Microsoft Actions Pane and Pane 3. What are they? I cannot delete them. They keep coming back.

Comment: @PatricK Also, I do not have AppData\Roaming, only AppData\Microsoft\Excel

Comment: @PatricK I solved it, but your post pointed me in the right direction. If you wouldn't mind posting your post as an answer, I'll award you the 50 points. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some auto loaded files in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel` (and some other folders too) which doesn't get loaded in Excel Safe Mode (`excel.exe /safe`).

You may want to list all the AddIns on the Excel onto ActiveSheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListAddIns()
    Dim oAddIn As AddIn, r As Long

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F1") = Array("Name", "FullName", "IsInstalled", "IsOpen", "CLSID", "progID")
    r = 2
    For Each oAddIn In Application.AddIns
        With oAddIn
             Cells(r, "A").Value = .Name
             Cells(r, "B").Value = .FullName
             Cells(r, "C").Value = .Installed
             Cells(r, "D").Value = .IsOpen
             Cells(r, "E").Value = .CLSID
             Cells(r, "F").Value = .progID
             r = r + 1
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

The `CLSID` and `progID` can be helpful if the addin is part of a software package (search in Registry).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove / delete macro, there's an description in official documentation.

[**Here's the link to it.**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b)

Comment: Thanks but the problem is it's doing this on ANY or NEW workbooks. So there must be a "hidden" macro in the Excel system itself. I've done a repair of the installation, but that didn't change anything.